# Data Entry for Two-Way Binding of Small Double

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm working on an application that does some custom financial data importing, and the user needs to be able to make small changes to numbers to make transactions balance. (sometimes rounding errors in one system or another cause imbalances and they need to be manually adjusted).  The errors are between two systems that I have no ability to control, and the nature of the changes requires a human to decide what change to make.

I've gotten data binding to work, except that there is a huge annoyance when entering data.  If the user wants to enter a very small negative number, the input keeps overriding their typing to remove negative signs and decimal places.

For example: If I try to type '-0.06' without stopping, I end up with just '6'.  If I stop before I get to the 6.  If I've typed '-0.0' and realize something is messed up, all there is is a '0'.  It's possible to enter the desired value, but I need to make a series of edits like '1006','10.06','0.06','-0.06'.  This is not very productive, and difficult to teach someone to do.

The XAML for my templatecolumn is as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LineAmount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=C2}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LineAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Any suggestions?  I've tried making a custom `IValueConverter` implementation, but still had the same issue.

Comment: [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the data binding or types.  The conversion behaviour works correctly, and my program does what it's supposed to do, the problem seems to be with the input behaviour.

Comment: You use `decimal` when you're handling financial numbers.

Comment: The number starts out decimal, but ends up double because it then gets passed to an odata service that is allowing me to interact with QuickBooks without using the QuickBooks SDK (which is poorly documented).  The wcf service reference generated classes requiring a double value.

Comment: What happens if you change the updatesourcetrigger to lostfocus?

Comment: @Core-One That does work.  It has an unfortunate effect somewhere else, but one I can live with.  There's a control further down that shows the net imbalance of the whole transaction, and it doesn't give instant feedback with this solution, but it's better than not being able to type a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think binding straight to a double is what is giving you the problem.  Thinking, when you first type in "-" that cannot be converted to a double, so the string format cannot be applied, breaking it.  You might be able to see this in the `Output` window in Visual Studio during runtime.  Instead, create a backing property that'll convert from string to double, then update the double amount.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LineAmount, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=C2}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LineAmountStr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Your view model class:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    private string _lineAmountStr;
    public string LineAmountStr
    {
        get { return _lineAmountStr; }
        set
        {
            double amt;
            if(double.TryParse(value, out amt))
            {
                LineAmount = amt;
            }
            _lineAmountStr = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LineAmountStr");
        }

    private double _lineAmount;
    public double LineAmount
    {
        get { return _lineAmount; }
        set
        {
            _lineAmount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LineAmount");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this one a try soon.  I cut some corners, due to a two week deadline from concept to something in production, so I'm currently binding to the Model directly.  I'll set up a ViewModel and see if this solves the problem (it looks like it will).

Comment: @Balrog30 although it may not be MVVM pure, you could just implement this inside of your Model and test it out.

Comment: That would be difficult as the Model is a generated Data Service.  I could probably inherit from it, but I'd be better off just to build the View Model, it's better practice anyway.  I wrote a lot of hacked together code just to get the thing working, time to do some refactoring.  For now I got the feature working by changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` for `LostFocus`.

Comment: So I did get this to work.  The one problem I encountered with this was that I tried to make the `LineAmount` setter update the `LineAmountStr`, which resulted in a `StackOverflowException` (try searching for that on Google, by the way... StackOverflow kinda killed that one).  It all works well now, though.  Thank you!